# How to change variables stored inside mouseMoved method in MouseMotionListener Java Class

Tags: java, events, mouseevent, mouselistener, mousemotionlistener

I am trying to write a mouse listener for my game. The basic idea is that I use mouse listener to (constantly update) track the x and y coordinates of my cursor and change the position of the player accordingly. I decided to use the mouseMoved method inside MouseMotionListener to accomplish this. I am supposed to press on the screen once in order to initiate mouse tracking of player, and once to stop. However, it seems my variables will not update inside mouseMoved. How do I update the variables inside the method?

```
private Handler handler;
public static int vel=5;
boolean pressed = false;
int run=0;

int x;
int y;

public  mouseListener(Handler handler){
    this.handler = handler;

}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    run++;

}


public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {

    this.x = event.getX() - 16;
    this.y = event.getY() - 16;
    System.out.println("Click"+run);
    int trun=run;

    if(trun%2==1) {
        System.out.println(x+" "+y);
        updateField(x,y);
    }


}

public void updateField(int tempx, int tempy) {
    int x=tempx;
    int y=tempy;
    for(int i=0; i<handler.object.size();i++){
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getID()== ID.Player){

            if(x>tempObject.getX()) {
                tempObject.setVelX(vel);
            }
            if(x<tempObject.getX()) {
                tempObject.setVelX(-1*vel);
            }
            if(x==tempObject.getX()) {
                tempObject.setVelX(0);
            }
            if(y>tempObject.getY()) {
                tempObject.setVelY(vel);
            }
            if(y<tempObject.getY()) {
                tempObject.setVelY(-1*vel);
            }
            if(y==tempObject.getY()) {
                tempObject.setVelY(0);
            }
            if(pressed==false) {
                tempObject.setVelY(0);
                tempObject.setVelX(0);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

By the end result, I should be able to click on the screen once, and the player should start following my mouse. I should then be able to click again to turn it off. Instead, the x and y values are updated but the player does not move and the on/off variable does not update inside mouseMoved().

Comment: Are the mouseClicked and mouseMoved methods being called at all?
If they are, then the only thing I can think of is that the mouseClicked event may be called twice for every one mouse click, making your run value always even.

Comment: by called, you mean added to the main game? Yes, I have this.addMouseMotionListener(new mouseListener(handler)); in my main method.

Comment: No, I mean does the code inside each method ever execute at all?  Have you put a println in each one to make sure they all work and are executed only once per mouse click or mouse movement?

Comment: yes, i put a println(x+" "+ y) inside mouseMoved and I can see the x and y change as i move the mouse around. I can also see a change in the run integer every time I click, but for whatever reason, run inside mouseMoved remains static.

Comment: I can only think of three possibilities:
run is being modified elsewhere that we cannot see,
run is a duplicate variable elsewhere,
or the mouseClicked event is being called twice for every real mouse click.
I suggest renaming the run variable and accessing it with "this.run".

Comment: the problem is the fact that run remains the same after being initialized. In other words, im modifying run in the general class, but the parameter inside mouseMove does not change from the original run=0.  I tried using @Override, but it didn't work. At this point, I just did what I wanted in a different way. Thanks for the ideas tho!!!